# Django specific language for each user is not respected

Tags: django, django-i18n

I need to change the default language for each user, but in my case the translation is not applied with the selected language. I store the preferred language for each user and set it as follows:

```
# set default language
    try:
        user_language_filter = UserFilters.objects.get(user=request.user, element__iexact='defaultLanguage')
        user_language = user_language_filter.value.lower()
    except UserFilters.DoesNotExist:
        user_language = 'en'

    if translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY in request.session:
        del request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY]

    translation.activate(user_language)
    request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = user_language

    print(translation.get_language())
```

Here I retrieve the stored language for the user and if not available, set it to 'en'. print() shows the correct language.
In my settings I have:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ....
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('fr', _('French'))
)
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../locale'),
)
```

makemessages and compilemessages create the files correctly in the given path.

In my ListView I have:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CompanyListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context.update({
        'page_title': _('Manage Companies'),
    })

    return context
```

The text to translate is in the locale files and also translated. I also printed the {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }} in the template which shows the wrong one. And in the template the page_title is not translated. Every help is appreciated.
**Update**
Seems that the translate in the view is not performed. If in a template I use the {% trans 'to translate' %} this is translated as well ass the model fields in the ModelForms.

Answer (score 1):

> Deprecated since version 3.0: The language won’t be stored in the
> session in Django 4.0. Use the LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME cookie instead.

That's the reason it does not work anymore

Answer (score 0):

I found that in the language .po file some translation are marked

```
#, fuzzy
```

and these translations are not shown.